# Alarm Manager is sometimes very long to run the intent

Tags: android, xamarin, alarmmanager

I got a problem with the AlarmManager. When the alarm is set, if the alarm's hour has already passed the intent is started which is great. But sometimes there is a very long time (from 30 secondes to 3 minutes) before the intent is started. If anyone knows why, I'm curious to understand.

Here is my code :

```
 public static void setAlarm()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            intent.SetAction("ExchangeGo");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
            Calendar dayCalendar = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);
            dayCalendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 8);
            dayCalendar.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 30);
            dayCalendar.Set(CalendarField.Second, 0);
            dayCalendar.Set(CalendarField.Millisecond, 0);       
            AlarmManager alarm = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService).JavaCast<AlarmManager>();
            alarm.Cancel(pendingIntent);
            alarm.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, dayCalendar.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalDay, pendingIntent);

        }
```

And here the intent :

```
   [BroadcastReceiver]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private  String SOMEACTION = "ExchangeGo";
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.Action;
            if (SOMEACTION.Equals(action))
            { 
                Intent intentService = new Intent(context, typeof(ExchangeService2));
                context.StartService(intentService);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is no problem with manifest cause it works, just a bit too long sometimes. And the problem is not from my second intent because I put a breakPoint just before and the waiting time is before the break point.

Anyone ?

Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `setRepeating()` **doesn't guarantee** that it will happen at precise time.
That's why you are getting delay of 30 secondes to 3 minutes.

Replace `setRepeating()` with `setExact()` refer documentation from [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

```
manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
```

To **repeat** this what you can do is, to **schedule this alarm again** after executing your **current event**. So when your **1st** intent gets executed schedule alarm for **2nd** event using `setExact()` only. This will guarantee the time accuracy you are expecting

Comment: First, thanks you . Then I got few question : will it repeat everyday and will it start if the time of  the alarm has passed ?

Comment: I have edited answer to show how to repeat using `setExact()`. Yes it will start exact at time which you have specified.

Comment: This answer is not really correct. setExact would have solved this issue in 2014. But in modern day Android 6+, setExact is going to be subject to long delays due to doze. The delays are going to be especially severe on Android 7+ devices that have a more aggressive form of doze that activates soon after the screen is turned OFF.